# Сравнение 2 массивов и вывод повторяющихся значений в 3 массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть 2 массива:

```
arr1 =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
arr2 =[n1,n2, n3,n4, n5,n6, n7,n8];
```

(значение 2-го массива пользователь вводит сам)
Нужно их сравнить между и собой и повторяющиеся значения вывести в 3-ий массив.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод `filter`:

```
arr2.filter(function(value) { 
    return -1 !== arr1.indexOf(value);
});
```

По сути, это функция для нахождения пересечения.

Пример взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript).

Документация [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Документация [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)